# Filter items in listview using the value selected on dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, listview, html.dropdownlistfor

Im newbie in asp.NET and i want to show a list of products in a listview depending on the value selected in a dropdown list (product category).

I've been searching but nothing helps me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use data view row filter for that:

```
String filterValue = drp.SelectedValue;
DataTable dt = Your datatable;
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "product_category = '" + filterValue + "'";
lstView.DataSource = dv;
lstView.DataBind();
```